# Ordering SSL *wildcard* certificate which from server certificates could be derived

Tags: https, ssl-certificate

We need an SSL wildcard certificate for our HTTPS servers all belonging to "*.domain.com".

Is it then possible for us to derive server certificates from the ordered wildcard certificate?

Reason: In case when a server should get compromised we have to be able to revoke the certificate for only this one server. All other servers using certificates derived from the same wildcard certificate should keep working.

Is it possible to purchase such a wildcard certificate? Any recommendations?

Comment: Sounds more like a SAN certificate. How many servers do you expect to cover with this certificate?

Comment: It's going to be 5-20 servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is simply not possible. You can not change the base domain once you have ordered an SSL Certificate for.

There is two possible solution you can evaluate.

1. Contact your SSL Certificate Authority and cancel that order (only if your order is under refund policy), ask for the refund and reorder the SSL for the Wildcard domain which you are wishing to secure.
2. Get a Multi Domain Wildcard SSL Certificate, it will allow you to secure multiple domain and sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't derive other certificates from a purchased SSL certificates. An ability to use certificate to sign other certificates is mainly controlled by a `Basic Constraints` certificate extension. This extension consist of two components, one of them (`isCA` attribute) determine whether this certificate can or cannot be used to sign other certificates.

When you purchase SSL certificate, you will get a certificate with `isCA = false` value in the `Basic Constraints` certificate extension.

If you want to control each server's certificate revocation, you have to purchase a separate certificate for each server (either, wildcard or for specific host names).